# onchange in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, internet-explorer

Why cant I use onChange in ie?
And is there a solution for this?

HTML:

```
<select id="auto_doors" style="display:none;" name="auto_doors" onchange="updateField(this.value, 'auto_fuel', 5, 6, this.parentNode.id), resetBelow(4,'auto'), show('auto_fuel')">
</select>
```

Function:

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie) { setTimeout(DoSomething, 0); } else { DoSomething(); }
        function updateField(str, id, prevvalue, value, vehicletype)
        {
        if (str=="")
          {
          document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="";
          return;
          } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","inc/form_rest.php?q="+str+"&prevvalue="+prevvalue+"&value="+value+"&vehicletype="+vehicletype,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery then why are you doing things like `window.XMLHttpRequest`? Oh, and you can use onchange in IE. What problems/errors are you having?

Comment: Yeah, if you are anyway carrying the weight of a library, you might as well use it to the fullest.

Comment: jQuery ajax doc http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: jQuery change doc http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Oh the first line was not meant to be there I found that somewhere and wanted to try it out. But when I run my script in IE it doesnt show any fields at all. While it works in the other browsers

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the on on change event to the auto_doors element like this instead:

```
$("#auto_doors").change(function(){
   updateField(this.value, 'auto_fuel', 5, 6, this.parentNode.id), resetBelow(4,'auto'), show('auto_fuel');
});
```

Comment: This still doesnt send the values to the next select box it just makes it appear, but it still works in other browsers like chrome and ff

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to fix this problem code will be something like this:

```
$('#auto_doors').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Three observations that may help:

1. There is no need to support IE6 and below anymore. `new XMLHttpRequest()` is sufficient.
2. You should set `onreadystatechange` *after* calling `.open()`. In some browsers (probaby just IE) calling `.open()` counts as a "new request" and clears the readystatechange handler.
3. Older versions of IE (IE7?) don't like `this.value` on a `<select>`. Instead, you should use `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`.